# Divide footer into two sections Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, footer

I want to divide my footer into two sections using xml.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a block to your footer section using XML.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainername="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.footer" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom_footer.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>

<move element="custom.footer" destination="footer" before="-" />
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/custom_footer.phtml

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```